# Render Xaml Controls from C# code behind in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

The Image that I have created from Code behind is visible in my Visual tree but is not rendered on screen when I run my app.

This is my Code Behind

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //Image that was created in Xaml
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///testimage.jpg"));

    //Image creation from C# code
    Image image1 = new Image();
    image1.Width = 200;
    image1.Height = 200;
    image1.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 0, 0);
    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///download.jpg"));
    //grid is the Grid name in Xaml
    grid.Children.Add(image1);
}
```

This is my XAML

```
<Page Name="HI"
x:Class="test1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:test1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grid">

    <Image x:Name="image" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="10,200,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your Xaml isn't complete. You are missing a closing tag for Page.

Comment: </Page> tag is just missing in the snippet. My code has Complete Xaml.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure, that 1) images are really available at paths you use? 2) you are not positioning them out of visible area?

Comment: Yeah i have checked image is available at path and they in screen space itself , can you please share your code?